# How to set URI correctly in a cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ember.js

I use cordova-cli to build an android app. The app can not access resource correctly. The error is

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

And I found the URI is

```
file:///assets/media/images/stop-sm.png
```

I think it should be

```
file:///android_asset/www/assets/media/images/stop-sm.png
```

but I don't know where and how to set the URI correctly.
Any advices or hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
[www]
  [assets]
    [media]
      [images]
         stop-sm.png
   xxx.js
   xxx.css
 index.html
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file://` instead of `file:///`?

Comment: the uri you entered would be helpful

Comment: nem, I think that file:/// is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this plugin for files URIS

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

It can abstract you from different versions or OS

in your case, you need

```
cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/assets/media/images/stop-sm.png"
```

EDIT:

Looking the comments, can be a whitelist problem. Try adding the plugin, if you dont have it, and add this meta tag to your main html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Comment: Del, thank you for quick response, I'll read the information of link. 
I set app.css file as follows
#stop {
  background:url(/assets/media/images/stop-sm.png) no-repeat;
}
and in js I write the code like
        this._btnPlayPause.style.background = "url(/assets/media/images/play-sm.png) no-repeat center";
They works well when I run the app on browser.

Comment: I am reading cordova-plugin-file. And I made a project using Visual Studio 2015,  index.css defines .app {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top; /* 170px x 200px */} 
and it works well. I am finding the reason.

Comment: What's the difference between the cordova-plugin-file and [cordova file](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/file/file.html)?

Comment: @Calvin, File is an api that allows you to navigate the device file system and cordova-plugin-file is the plugin that equips your app to use the File api.

Comment: Del, Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I read [Ember CLI and Cordova](http://lelandbatey.com/posts/2015/02/ember-and-cordova/), 
and build my app for an android device. It works well when running on broswer (localhost:4200) after ran 'ember s'.
The app works as well but without images.

Comment: Nice, please post your solution when you get it ;)

Comment: Del, I have solved the problem, though it is a little weired.

Comment: I changed background:url(/assets/media/images/play-sm.png) to   background:url(media/images/play-sm.png) in css file, and background = “url(/assets/media/images/play-sm.png)" to background =   "url(assets/media/images/play-sm.png)" in js file.
’

Comment: I hope the url keeps same format in both css file and js file, I feel the difference is a little weired. However, the problem have been solved. I checked it run well both in browser and in device.

Comment: Read the first couple sentences of about [asset](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation).